# How to prevent screen going blank in a virtual machine running RHEL6?

Tags: java, linux, selenium

I have a vmware esxi virtual machine running RHEL6.3 which acts as a hudson ci server. I am trying to setup the box so that it can run my selenium testcases initiated from hudson. The application to test requires browser authentication and using the format

```
"http://username:password@URL"
```

does not work, so as a workaround, for each test case I spawn a thread right after opening the URL in firefox, which uses robot from awt to perform the simple sequence- "type username -> press tab -> type password -> press enter". This is a quick and dirty hack but it works. My problem is that this sequence does not work unless I open the virtual monitor in vsphere client. My guess is that unless the virtual monitor is open, the screen is going blank and that is throwing the robot sequence off-track. Now before initiating each test from hudson, i have to open the virtual monitor in my workstation and keep it open. I have tried disabling sleep from power management and setting kernel parameters "apm=off acpi=off" but to no avail. I have a hunch it would have worked if the box was a physical machine with a physical monitor, but currently I don't have any spare boxes to test the theory.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the screen saver / screen blanking timeout from within the Desktop environment; that's an X11 issue, nothing to do with the kernel.